# How can I change the color of a third-party React component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using a React library called `vertical-timeline-component-react`.
https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/vertical-timeline-component-react

```
    <Fragment>
      <Timeline>
        <Content>
          <ContentYear
            startMonth="12"
            monthType="text"
            startDay="24"
            startYear="2016"
          />
          <ContentBody style={{color: 'red'}} title="Amazing Title">
          </ContentBody>
        </Content>
        <Content>
          <ContentYear
            startMonth="12"
            monthType="text"
            startDay="24"
            startYear="2016"
          />
          <ContentBody title="Amazing Title">
          </ContentBody>
        </Content>
      </Timeline>
    </Fragment>
```

I used the sample code provided in the example, which renders two `Content` components.
What I want to do is to change the color of the text in the `ContentBody` and make the color different for each component.

As you can see, I tried using inline styling `<ContentBody style={{color: 'red'}} title="Amazing Title">`, but it didn't work.

Then I tried to inspect the element and found out that the className of the text body is `.jertxS`.
I then created a `styles.css` to change the font color of the class. It worked, but it applies to all `ContentBody`s. What I want is to have them different colors.

It seems like the library doesn't provide a template for doing it. In this case, what is the way to customize the color?

Comment: Yeah, that is what I tried and was mentioned in my question. I found out that it uses the `.jertxS` className. But what I want is, I want them to have different color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When in doubt, check the source code.  We live in a wonderful time where most npm packages you install have public source code.  This library's source is on [github](https://github.com/Proskynete/vertical-timeline-component-react) and you can view what the ContentBody component is doing [here](https://github.com/Proskynete/vertical-timeline-component-react/blob/master/src/components/content_body/index.js#L37)

```
const ContentBody = (props) => {
    const { title, children } = props;

    return (
        <BodyComponent className='body-component'>
            <BodyComponentTitle className='title-body-component'>
                {title}
            </BodyComponentTitle>
            {children}
        </BodyComponent>
    );
};
```

It looks like they are using a static className of 'body-component' that you might be able to target.  It does not appear that they are passing style or className thru from props so you have to work with what you got, or fork and extend the library to meet your needs and optionally push back your changes so others can benefit.

Depending on how radical your changes are you can also just copy the src files into your project and start altering and consuming them directly.  The project is MIT licensed so your are free to embed the code in your app.

Comment: Thanks @Frank! I was actually thinking of doing this and forked his repo. I am quite new to doing this (forking and modifying a 3rd party library). Usually, if a library is build on top of `create-react-app`, the `npm run start` command would run the app, but this one is kinda different. How can I run his code? `npm run start` gives me `webpack is watching the files… Entrypoint main = index.js`

Comment: Looks like this project is using [jest tests](https://github.com/Proskynete/vertical-timeline-component-react/tree/master/__tests__).  Try running [npm run test:watch](https://github.com/Proskynete/vertical-timeline-component-react/blob/master/package.json#L22) and see what happens.  It does not look like there is anything in the project to let you see the output in browser like create-react-app does, it looks like you just edit src files and run test to ensure your changes are correct.  I could be wrong though, I have never used jest testing.

Answer (score 0):

Careful using that class, as it may change on your next build.

First check if they have any colour prop in their API.
If not, check if passing in a “className” will stick.
If not, use a more complex css selector like ‘div > div:nth-of-type > ...’

Answer (score 0):

Like @Alan P said, try adding a className attribute and write a class in your css file.

**component.js**

```
<ContentBody className="red-color" title="Amazing Title">
</ContentBody>
```

**index.css**

```
.red-color{ color: red !important }
```

That should override the current color styling